# Android NDK Gradle setting error

Tags: android, android-ndk

With Android Studio, I'm trying to include Android NDK following guidance but the application cannot built.

Experimental Plugin User Guide - Android Studio Project Site http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/gradle-experimental

I got an error:

```
Error: Please fix the project's Gradle settings.
Fix Gradle wrapper and re-import project Gradle settings
```

I cannot find where to fix.

Android Studio and Gradle Version is below.

- Android Studio: 1.5.1
- Gradle: 2.10 (I think)

gradle-wrapper.properties is:

```
#Thu May 12 23:11:00 JST 2016
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.10-all.zip
```

project build.gradle is:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle-experimental:0.7.0-alpha4'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

application build.gradle is:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.model.application'

model {
    android {
        compileSdkVersion 23
        buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"
        ndk {
            moduleName "native"
        }

        defaultConfig {
            applicationId "com.example.mysamplendkapp"
            minSdkVersion.apiLevel 15
            targetSdkVersion.apiLevel 22
            versionCode 1
            versionName "1.0"

            buildConfigFields {
                create() {
                    type "int"
                    name "VALUE"
                    value "1"
                }
            }
        }
        buildTypes {
            release {
                minifyEnabled false
                proguardFiles.add(file("proguard-rules.pro"))
            }
        }
        productFlavors {
            create("flavor1") {
                applicationId "com.app"
            }
        }
        sources {
            main {
                java {
                    source {
                        srcDir "src"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
}
```

Thanks,

Comment: you could review latest revs here : http://ph0b.com/new-android-studio-ndk-support/